# Invoking xterm prompt through call_usermodehelper

Tags: linux, kernel, xterm

Everyone,

I try to invoking xterm with the root privilege from a Linux kernel module by calling the function `call_usermodehelper`. My code is as follows:

```
char* envp[] = {"HOME=/", NULL};
char* argv[] = {"/usr/bin/xterm", NULL};

int ret = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);

printk(KERN_INFO "retval: %d\n", ret);
```

The result shows that ret is 256. I think the command is successfully carried out. However, I did not see the xterm window popped up.

Any one can help me about this issue? Or is there any other way to realize what I want?

Comment: It is not successfully being carried out; the return value you are seeing is indicating an error.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing some necessary environment variables. Try this:

```c
char* envp[] = {"HOME=/", "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", NULL};
char* argv[] = {"/usr/bin/xterm", NULL};

int ret = call_usermodehelper(argv[0], argv, envp, UMH_WAIT_PROC);

printk(KERN_INFO "retval: %d\n", ret);
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems still not working. Return value is 256 and "ps -ef | grep xterm" shows nothing. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The likely reason is that the `DISPLAY` environment variable (along with some others) is dropped when you sudo'd to root.  To work around this, you should either set the variable or pass the `-display` option on the command line.

You may also need to modify settings with `xhost` (though the usual advice seems to be simply to open it up to *all*, which is not good).

For related discussion:

- [set DISPLAY variable](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/set-display-variable-132371/)
- [run x programs as root.](https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-612614-start-0.html)
- [unable open xterm](http://lists.freedesktop.org/pipermail/xorg/2011-May/052825.html)

and documentation:

- [xhost](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?xhost%201)
- [xauth](http://www.lehman.cuny.edu/cgi-bin/man-cgi?xauth%201)

Answer (score 0):

**Launching a terminal from a kernel module**
An example of solving the task of launching the terminal when pressing the "F12" key. Operating system CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)
[root@osi83 module_run_prog_key]# uname -r
3.10.0-1160.59.1.el7.x86_64

1. Сreate a file scankey.c

   #include <linux/module.h>

#include <linux/init.h>

#include <linux/interrupt.h>

#include <asm/io.h> /* Функция inb(port) */

#define SHARED_IRQ 1 //keyboard irq ... cat /proc/interrups

#define KBD_SCANCODE_MASK   0x7f

#define KBD_STATUS_MASK     0x80

static int irq = SHARED_IRQ, my_dev_id, irq_counter = 0;

module_param( irq, int, S_IRUGO );

static irqreturn_t my_interrupt( int irq, void *dev_id )

{

unsigned char scancode;

unsigned char status;

int value, valstatus;

int rc;

char *argv[] = { "/.1/gterm.sh", "\n", NULL };

char *envp[] = { "PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin", "DISPLAY=:0.0",NULL };

irq_counter++;

status = inb(0x64); // cat /proc/ioports | grep keyboard

scancode = inb(0x60);// cat /proc/ioports | grep keyboard

value = (int)scancode & KBD_SCANCODE_MASK;

valstatus = (int)scancode & KBD_STATUS_MASK;

printk( KERN_INFO "In the ISR: counter = %d, key=%d, status%d\n", irq_counter, value , valstatus);

```
    if(value==88) // Code of key "F12"

    {

         rc = call_usermodehelper( argv[0], argv, envp, 0 );

         printk(KERN_INFO "retval: %d\n", rc);

     if( rc )

     {

      printk( KERN_INFO "failed to execute : %s\n", argv[ 0 ] );

      return rc;

     }

         printk( KERN_INFO "execute : %s %s\n", argv[ 0 ], argv[ 1 ] );


    while(!valstatus)

    {

     scancode = inb(0x60);

     valstatus = (int)scancode & KBD_STATUS_MASK;

    }


    }
```

return IRQ_NONE; /* we return IRQ_NONE because we are just observing */

}

static int __init my_init( void )

{

if ( request_irq( irq, my_interrupt, IRQF_SHARED, "my_interrupt", &my_dev_id ) )

return -1;

printk( KERN_INFO "Successfully loading ISR handler on IRQ %d\n", irq );

return 0;

}

static void __exit my_exit( void )

{

synchronize_irq( irq );

free_irq( irq, &my_dev_id );

printk( KERN_INFO "Successfully unloading, irq_counter = %d\n", irq_counter );

}

module_init( my_init );

module_exit( my_exit );

MODULE_AUTHOR( "Osintsev Alexandr, Russian, Miass city" );

MODULE_DESCRIPTION( "Start gnome-terminal on pressing "F12" key" );

MODULE_LICENSE( "GPL v2" );

---

*******END FILE scankey.c****

---

2. Сreate a file Makefile

CURRENT = $(shell uname -r)

KDIR = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/build

PWD = $(shell pwd)

DEST = /lib/modules/$(CURRENT)/misc

TARGET = scankey

obj-m:= $(TARGET).o

default:

```
$(MAKE) -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
```

clean:

```
@rm -f *.o .*.cmd .*.flags *.mod.c *.order

@rm -f .*.*.cmd *.symvers *~ *.*~ TODO.*

@rm -fR .tmp*

@rm -rf .tmp_versions
```

---

******* END Makefile ********

---

3. Create a file /.1/gterm.sh

#!/bin/bash

gnome-terminal

---

*******END gterm.sh file*****

---

4. Building and running the module

[root@osi83 module_run_prog_key]# make clean;make;insmod ./scankey.ko irq=1

5. Press key "F12"...

Note:
[root@osi83 module_run_prog_key]# cat /proc/interrupts
CPU0       CPU1
0:   10382613          0   IO-APIC-edge      timer

**1:       2222      25479   IO-APIC-edge      i8042, my_interrupt**

8:          0          1   IO-APIC-edge      rtc0
...

...

...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).